# copy and pasting data to another worksheet with loop and if condition

Tags: excel, vba

The following code seems to run smoothly but nothing was copied onto the desired page

```
Sub a2()


Sheets.Add.Name = "25 degree"
Sheets("25 degree").Move after:=Sheets("data")


Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To 33281

If Cells(x, 1).Value = 25 Then

    Cells("x,1:x,2:x,3:x,4:x,5:x,6").Copy
     Worksheets("25 degree").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: `x` is a variable, so you cannot include it inside of your string... and you would want to use `Range` instead of `Cells` in your case... `Range(x & ",1:" & x & ",2")` etc...

Comment: Also I highly recommend not to use `.Select` or `ActiveSheet` instead specify the sheet for each `Cells()` object according to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: All the code is strange, I am afraid... Besides the wrong range definition, your code adds a new sheet, which will become your `ActiveSheet`. Then You iterate between the empty newly sheet A:A range and apoteoticaly select it to paste something... In which range would you like to paste the values?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not to use `.Select` or `ActiveSheet` instead specify the sheet for each `Cells()` object according to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomeCoypExample()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        'better define by name
        'Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("source sheet")

    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")) 'add at the correct position and set it to a variable
    wsDestination.Name = "25 degree" 'so you can use the variable to access the new added worksheet.

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To 33281 'don't use fixed end numbers (see below if you meant to loop until the last used row)
        If wsSource.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = 25 Then
            With wsSource
                .Range(.Cells(iRow, 1), .Cells(iRow, 6)).Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A1")
                'this line will copy columns 1 to 6 of the current row
                'note you need to specify the range where you want to paste
                'if this should be dynamic see below.
            End With
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

If you want to loop until the last used row you can get that with something like

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column A
```

If you want to paste into the next free row in your destination worksheet instead of a fixed range `Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A1")` you can use the same technique as above to finde the next free row:

```
Dim NextFreeRow As Long
NextFreeRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

So you can use that in your paste destination:
`Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A" & NextFreeRow)`